# How can I protect my amplifier, MCU, and laptop from damage in my application circuit?

Tags: microcontroller, amplifier, ground, safety, piezo

I am trying to integrate a few devices for a laser stabilization system. I have a tentative circuit diagram that I'm asking for more expert guidance in implementing. I am using an [MX200 from PiezoDrive](https://www.piezodrive.com/modules/mx200-high-performance-piezo-driver/), a Teensy 3.6, my laptop, and a [Meanwell 150W 24V Supply](https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/LRS-150/LRS-150-SPEC.PDF). I feel as though it should be straightforward, but I am relatively inexperienced and have broken an amplifier by accident. After plugging in a speaker to my laptop to simulate vibration, it became earth referenced, and after probing with an earthed oscilloscope I most likely destroyed the amp (rookie mistake, I know). I have purchased a USB Isolator for my speaker and audio interface, which should fix that problem.

I follow the most basic setup posted on PiezoDrive's website, and my load is [this mirror mount](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=POLARIS-K2S2P), with 350nF capacitance. 
Thanks, and any advice and/or questions would be appreciated. Here is the block diagram and basic application circuit for the amplifier (bimorph load not applicable).

[image]
[image: block diag]
[image: most basic setup]

Comment: Please show a schematic of all wiring between the devices and power supplies.

Comment: It should be in the first hyperlink in my post - is that sufficient?

Comment: Sorry I missed the link. Any reason you can't show the image in the question like the other two?

Comment: My guess is that it was too high resolution... I will investigate that right now.

Comment: I was wrong - it should be displayed normally now.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything inherently wrong with this. Make sure your ground return paths are good, and be careful what you hook your oscilloscope ground lead up to in the future and you should be fine. There's no reasonable way to set this up where you can hook a ground clip up to it willy nilly without risking burning something out.